# Xarray- ValueError: unrecognized chunk manager dask - must be one of: []

Tags: dask, python-xarray, netcdf

I'm attempting to look into a NetCDF file, and I've read that I can work with them if they're larger than available memory by "breaking them into chunks" using dask. However, I get:

ValueError: unrecognized chunk manager dask - must be one of: []

I'm also not sure if breaking it into chunks a certain size works the way I attempted...

I expected it to print the dataset showing variables with type dask.array and a chunksize attribute

I do have dask installed, but it can't find the module if I attempt to import it

Other people having this isssue have said installing an older version of xarray worked, but it didn't.

I'm *very* new to python, so I'll do my best to provide more info if needed.
Here's what I've got up to the issue:

> import numpy as np
>
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> import xarray as xr
>
> file = 'jan2mT.nc'
>
> folder = 'foldername'
>
> filename = folder+file
>
> ds = xr.open_dataset(filename,decode_times=True,chunks={'time': '250MB'})
>
> print(ds)

Comment: This seems like your problem: `I do have dask installed, but it can't find the module if I attempt to import it`. There must be something wrong with your environment. Without more information though, there's not much we can do here.